# How to write a batch file to put a file in MATLAB's bin directory

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a batch file through which I should be able to place a file in MATLAB's bin directory. This batch file should work on any PC with MATLAB.

I am trying following command:

```
Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin"
```

It is working, but it will not work on other PCs as the MATLAB directory is hard-coded.
Is there any way to take care of this issue?

Comment: don't know matlab. If it's an .EXE and if it's in the Path, `where matlab.exe` should tell you where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are searching for a full path for `matlab` executable, i.e. something like `matlab.exe`. I do not have `matlab` installed, however next script could help (operational `xcopy` command is `echo`ed merely for debugging purposes...).
**Edited** to ensure whether the file was really copied:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "Executable=gimp-*.exe"   :: change this line no narrow your search
set "CopyToFldr="
call :getExecutable "where"
if not defined CopyToFldr call :getExecutable "where /R C:\"
if defined CopyToFldr (
  echo Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "%CopyToFldr%"
  dir /B "%CopyToFldr%abc.txt"
  Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "%CopyToFldr%"
  dir /B "%CopyToFldr%abc.txt"
) else (
  echo %Executable% not found
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:getExecutable
echo %~1
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('%~1 %Executable% 2^>Nul') do (
  echo "%%~dpG" folder contains %%~nxG 
  set "CopyToFldr=%%~dpG"
)
goto :eof
```

**Output** from user's command prompt (`cmd.exe`):

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31555349.bat
where
where /R C:\
"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\" folder contains gimp-2.8.exe
"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\" folder contains gimp-console-2.8.exe
Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\"
File Not Found
.\abc.txt
Access denied
File Not Found

==>
```

**Output** from elevated command prompt (run `cmd.exe` as administrator):

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31555349.bat
where
where /R C:\
"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\" folder contains gimp-2.8.exe
"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\" folder contains gimp-console-2.8.exe
Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\"
File Not Found
.\abc.txt
1 File(s) copied
abc.txt

==>
```

Comment: have you checked if the file was really copied?

Comment: @scmg I have _not_ checked if the file was really copied: first, this additional question exceeds the OQ topic, and second, I _know_ it could require elevated privileges :)

Comment: and result is: the batch runs, but the file `.\abc.txt` is not copied without any error or warning on screen, and question is not answered. Sorry, but i'm also looking for a working solution :-)

Comment: Hi @josefZ I have matlab.exe in two directory it is coping the file at only one place. as I am new to batch file programming, so can you please edit the code so that it can copy to both folders. BTW I will try to edit it from my end.

Comment: Just move `xcopy` command into the `:getExecutable` subroutine. Instead of `set "CopyToFldr=%%~dpG"`, I'd use `Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "%%~dpG"` there. However, I don't know how-to treat if the destination  file exists already: `xcopy /Y` switch to overwrite without prompting or to retain it:  either `Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "%%~dpG" 2>NUL` or do `xcopy` conditionally as `if not exist "%%~dpGabc.txt" Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "%%~dpG"`

Answer (score 0):

To get the installation folder (root folder) of MATLAB, you can use the [`matlabroot`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabroot.html) function.

```
mr = matlabroot
mr = 
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014A_64
```

You can append the `bin` folder using the [`fullfile`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) function

```
dest = fullfile(matlabroot,'bin')
```

`fullfile` concatenates paths ensuring that a separator (`/` or `\`) is used and that the correct one is used (`\` on Windows, `/` on Linux).

Further I would recommend to use built-in [`copyfile`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html) function to copy files or folders from within MATLAB, but I don't know `Xcopy` - it might be suited as well.

As these are MATLAB functions, you can put everything in a MATLAB script, save it as `whatever.m` and then run MATLAB from the command line to execute this script:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run whatever.m; exit"
```

This also comes with the advantage that it should work on any operating system.

Comment: This matlabroot doesn't work on windows command prompt, it works on matlab command prompt, I want to solve above problem using batch file only, so that same file we can run on other PCs. I don't want to open matlab manually and get bin directory.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I misunderstood your question. As I am no Bash expert, I at least added a paragraph to my answer, which describes how you can run this from the Bash shell, so my answer really does answer the question and works. Maybe somebody else can come up with a Bash-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will create a directory first and then copies your file , if the directory already exist it will only copy file.

```
MD "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin" && Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin" || echo Directory already exists || Xcopy ".\abc.txt" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin"
```

Comment: What if Matlab's actual bin directory is "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin  instead of "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin. As in Other PCs which matlab is installed you don't know.

Comment: ok , is  destination path fixed or it keeps on changing ? , if it keeps on changing do you know the folder structure in advance , or is it random which you do not know.

Comment: Destination path folder structure is fixed as C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin   but this R2014b may change to R2013b or other versions
one way to know matlab directory is   where matlab.exe    command , It returns directory of matlab.exe, but I don't know how to make use of it.

Comment: @Ranjan: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where matlab.exe') do set matpath=%%~dpi`